# PHP RESTful service

Tags: php, xml, rest

After a little advise. Please excuse any language I use to describe things, that may not be the correct terms.

Basically tasked with creating a REST service using php. I've got an XML file. Snippet below.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<crimes year='2013' xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="stats.xsd">
    <data country='England' region='North East Region' area='Cleveland'>
        <heading name='Victim-based crime'>
            <category name='Violence against the person'>
                <number type='Homocide' total='3'/>
                <number type='Violence with injury' total='3737'/>
                <number type='Violence without injury' total='2630'/>
            </category>
            <category type='Sexual offences' total='563' /> 
            <category type='Robbery' total='259' />
            <category type='Theft offences'>
                <number type='Burglary' total='4561' />
                <number type='Domestic Burglary' total='2054' />
                <number type='Non-domestic burglary' total='2057' />
                <number type='Vehicle offences' total='3329' />
                <number type='Theft from the person' total='372' />
                <number type='Bycycle theft' total='994' />
                <number type='Shoplifting' total='5174' />
                <number type='All other theft offences' total='5381' />
            </category>
            <category type='Criminal damage and arson' total='7934' />
        </heading>  
        <heading name='Other crimes against society'>
            <category type='Drug offences' total='2116' />
            <category type='Possession of weapons offences' total='267' />
            <category type='Public order offences' total='1342' />
            <category type='Miscellaneous crimes against society' total='405' />
            <category type='Fraud' total='405' />
        </heading>
    </data>
</crimes>
```

It contains multiple data sets.

So I've tried using simpleXML to display the content on the XML file.

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$xml=simplexml_load_file("stats.xml");
print_r($xml);
```

The code displays arrays, each containing one element on the XML file. I've also tried using DOM, but I've been advised simpleXML is the way to go, but that's the extent of advise so far.

I'm basically looking to extract content from the XML file, based on what is entered in the url, e.g. http://www.url.com/crimes/country/ using GET and display the content in XML format relevant to the input.

I've managed to display the first element in the xml file using:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("stats.xml");

    echo "<h2>".$xml->getName()."</h2><br />";

    foreach($xml->children() as $crimes)
    {
        echo "Country : ".$crimes->attributes()->country."<br />";
        echo "Region : ".$crimes->attributes()->region."<br />";
        echo "Area : ".$crimes->attributes()->area."<br />"; 
    }
```

but that's displaying just the `<data..>` and it's not using the GET method.

I'm completely lost, I don't even know where to proceed, I've searched through Google for days and I've found nothing. Any advise or tips would be excellent.

Comment: So, next step is capturing what's in the URL? How have you tried to do that?

Comment: Tried using the GET function..

    $var = $_GET["name"];
     echo $var;

Comment: @user3188584 so you are passing parameters like this `/crimes/country/?name=somename`

Comment: Yes, using dirty urls to start with. Name being a country, and then displaying the info relevant to that country, ultimately then using crimes/country/?name=England&area=Cleveland&type=Homicide

Comment: Might be easiest to assemble an [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) query in a string and [run that](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php).

Comment: Wiseguy is wise. XPath could be the easiest way to go.

Comment: Ok, will look into XPath. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easiest to assemble an [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) query dynamically, then run it with the [`->xpath()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) method.

Something like this would work for your particular example above:

```
$xpath = sprintf(
    '/crimes/data[@country="%s"][@area="%s"]/heading/category/number[@type="%s"]',
    $_GET['name'],
    $_GET['area'],
    $_GET['type']
);

$nodeList = $xml->xpath($xpath);
echo 'Number: ', $nodeList[0]['total'];
```

<sup>Working example: http://ideone.com/Smh1ax</sup>

You'll likely need to add logic to build your query differently to grab other pieces of data depending what variables are provided in the URL. Hopefully this gets you on the right track.